# Dispensing Text In PHP

Tags: php

In my php file called "account.php" I have

```
<?php 
// First we execute our common code to connection to the database and start the session 
require("common.php"); 
// At the top of the page we check to see whether the user is logged in or not 
if(empty($_SESSION['user'])) 
{ 
    // If they are not, we redirect them to the login page. 
    header("Location: login.php"); 
    // Remember that this die statement is absolutely critical.  Without it, 
    // people can view your members-only content without logging in. 
    die("Redirecting to login.php"); 
}          
?> 
<html>
<body>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/gif" href="favicon.gif" />
    <?php include("header.php"); ?>
    <div id="main-box">
        <ul>
            <li class="buttons">
<?php 
//TEXT BOX WITH A LINE FROM **TEXT.txt** SHOULD APPEAR HERE AFTER USER CLICKS BUTTONS 
?>
                <input type="button" name="account" value="Get Your Account" onclick="#" />
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I want it so when the user clicks the button, a text box appears and displays ONE line from the text file and when they view it, it deletes it from the text file. 
   **text.txt**

```
Eddie so after the user clicks the button it displays this line to them and then deletes it after so that the next line would then become the first line. 
Apples
Hello
People
```

If you don't understand my question then please let me know and I will try to explain further. Thank you. :)

Comment: PHP is parsed before ever being sent to the browser. If you are looking to interact with the user through buttons, you'll need a client-side script such as javascript.

Comment: I have updated my question to try and make it easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation is to use javascript (or jQuery) to make an AJAX call to a PHP script that handles the reading of the text file, and then deletes the top line. The javascript would then need to take the script's response (the line on the text file) and add the text box to the page.